# How can i customize the view for invite friends using Game Center?

Tags: iphone, xcode, game-center, gamekit

I am using Game center for my app and it shows me the standard  view for the game center invites which does not match with the theme of my app . Is there anyway by which i can customize the look for the invite friends as my theme ?How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no.

The Game Center UI  cannot be changed, at least without being rejected from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the these two classes:

- `GKMatchRequest` [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)
- Either `GKMatcher` [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmaker_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKMatchmaker) or `GKTurnBasedMatch` [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKTurnBasedMatch) depending on whether your app is turn based.